# Printing properties of an object in two ways

Tags: python, class, oop

I have been given an assignment involving object oriented programming. Two of the small functions within the class ask to be able to display the properties of the object in two different ways

```
>>> r1
Rectangle(Point(0,0),Point(1,1),'blue')
```

and

```
>>> print(r1)
I am a blue rectangle with bottom left corner at (2, 3) and top right corner at (2, 3).
```

Here is the code I have written for both but for some reason it is only returning the sentece and not the other:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'I am a '+str(self.color)+' rectangle with bottom left corner at '+str(self.p1.get())+' and top right corner at '+str(self.p2.get())+'.'

def __str_(self):
    return 'Rectangle('+str(self.p1)+','+str(self.p2)+','+str(self.color)+')'
```

but when I test it my results display:

```
>>> r1
I am a red rectangle with bottom left corner at (0, 0) and top right corner at (1, 1).
>>> print(r1)
I am a red rectangle with bottom left corner at (0, 0) and top right corner at (1, 1).
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you clarify more?

Comment: @IronFist My program only returns the "I am..." sentence and not the Rectangle statement

Comment: You are missing a trailing underscore in your `__str__` method; that is, you've defined a new method `__str_` rather than overriding `__str__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `_` in the `__str_` it should be `__str__`